# WSO2 identity server user session destroying endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I used "https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/api/users/v1/me/sessions" to kill all the sessions.

[image]

[image]

Service running without a issue. But sessions are still active. What is wrong with me here. I attached images here my response from c# code and response from postman.

Comment: Did you check whether session is active from WSO2IS side? Use Get Api and check the response. IS migh have killed the session. But application session might be active

Comment: Yes, when i invoke GET request it gives me "{}" empty string even without deleting it. What could be the reason to get empty sessions. When i go to "localhost:9443/myaccount/overview" i can see my active sessions from UI.. Where could be the missing part for me. Here is my endpoint "localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/api/users/v1/me/sessions". Am i missing any configuration in admin console

Comment: Is there any possibility the WSO2IS version i use is not supporting this. My server version is "5.12.0-m12".

Comment: I figured out this. Problem was the username and password i have passed were wrong. thank you.